# Java Split String list into a string list

Tags: java, arrays, list, split

I am trying to split a config into an array but i am having
some issues.

My config looks like:

`Enchantments: Durability:3 Unbreaking:2`

I want my array to look like `[0]Durability [1]3 [2]Unbreaking [3]2`

But i can only get the Durability to go into [0] and 3 into [1] it
wont go further than that. All the code works, here's all you need.
Help! Code tags are the worst on the website and i cannot get them for
the life of me, So here

```
if (((String)nodes.get(nodeapi)).contains("enchantments:")){
        System.out.println("found");
        ench = ((String)nodes.get(nodeapi)).replace("enchantments:", "");
        System.out.println(ench);
        String[] enc = ench.split(" ");
        System.out.println("0 " + enc[0]);
        System.out.println("1 " + enc[1]);
        int p = 0;
        for (int i2=0;i2<enc.length*2;i2++){
                p++;
                encha = enc[i2].split(":");
                System.out.println("Passed loop: " + p + " with encha: "+encha[i2]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Be careful.  The code you posted replaces `"enchantments:"` with an empty string, but your example has a space after `"enchantments:"`, and this space will be left in the string.  If you use `split` on `":| "` as others have suggested, this will leave an empty string in `enc[0]`, instead of `"Durability"`, because `split()` will treat the leading space as a delimiter.  If this is a problem, use `trim()` before `split()`.

Comment: (Or do as one of the answers did, and include the space in the string that you `replace`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the regex `":| "` when you split the string.

As in

```
string.split(":| ");
```

So your code will look like:

```
String[] enc = ench.split(":| ");
```

(if ench is `Durability:3 Unbreaking:2`

then the array will be what you want.

Comment: So how would that look in my array when i do that? Do i keep my code the same just change the split and it will work? Because its working for the first 2, [0] Says durability and [1] says 3 But its not taking the second item in the list im trying to split and split it through the list i need it to go into. I need it to split the item from enc into encha 0 and 1, and enc[1] into enc 2 and 3 and so on

Comment: What is the string that you are splitting?

Comment: Replace the 5 line with ench.split(":| "); as JClassic says and u will have an array of length 4 which contains exactly the elements you want [0]Durability [1]3 [2]Unbreaking [3]2

Comment: ZOMG Thank you guys so much, I have been jabbing at this for around 8 hours on and off. You helped me so much!!!! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
String x = "Enchantments: Durability:3 Unbreaking:2";
x = x.replace("Enchantments: ", "");
String[] values = x.split(":|\\s");
for(String val : values)
   System.out.println(val);
```